# InvalidCastException was unhandled vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi there this error message keeps appearing when i try to calculate my data.

[image]

Comment: You miss ```Console``` before ```WriteLine```. This way you are calling [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw69s8t(v=vs.90).aspx) which expects integer.

Comment: Thanks dee!much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You're using FileSystem.WriteLine rather than Console.WriteLine.

See the difference here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx